# ms logparser export to sql statements

Tags: sql, sqlite, logparser

is it possible to use the [logparser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) commandline utility to output sql statements as text?  it seems bent on actually connecting to sqlserver and performing the inserts automatically.  i just want a text file with the table creation and insert statements so that i can run them against sqlite instead of sqlserver.  or if you know how to get logparser utility to work with sqlite directly that would be fine also.  i'm really not in the mood to write my own utility, though it wouldn't be too hard with the logparser.dll goodness.  at the moment, i think i'm going to have to use logparser to export to xml instead of sql, then use a clever xslt script to turn the xml into sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the `-o:SQL` option and specify the SQLite driver:

```
logparser -i:W3C "select * from filename.w3c"
    -o:SQL -database:yourdb.db -driver:"SQLite3 ODBC Driver"
```

Comment: interesting approach.  i don't have the sqlite3 odbc driver installed, but i could give this a try.  thanks for the feedback.